# Writing point coordinate to txt file in C

Tags: c, file, text-files

I have a set of eye coordinates and I want to save them into a text file in C (For OpenCV) like this:

254 234  344  434  this is first set, including left and right eye co-ordinate
455 345  344  345  next one
and so on..

Comment: So, what did you try? Show us how far you've gotten and we might be able to assist you.

Comment: my code is long i can not post it all .... i only have done for one eye coordinate in a line in txt file but i need more than one ... in the next lines in the txt file

Comment: You don't have to reproduce the entire program, but at least show us the definition of your coordinate types and where you're writing it to the file.

Comment: Taking a wild guess. You need to put your call to fopen and fclose outside of the loop around the coordinates, if you put fopen and fclose inside the loop you will only get one line in your file, because everytime you open the file you will delete it's existing contents. As I said just a guess, **post the code**, or don't you really want to get help?

Comment: ok i will post them in order... this is the first part, just past them into an editor and have a look!

Comment: void detectAndDraw( Mat& img,
                   CascadeClassifier& cascade, CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                   double scale)
{
 int I=0;  //writing
 FILE *f;
 f = fopen("pos.txt","w");
    int i = 0;
    double t = 0;
    vector<Rect> faces;
    const static Scalar colors[] =  { CV_RGB(0,0,255),
        CV_RGB(0,128,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,128,0),
        CV_RGB(255,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,255)} ;

Comment: Mat gray, smallImg( cvRound (img.rows/scale), cvRound(img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1 );

    cvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    resize( gray, smallImg, smallImg.size(), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR );
    equalizeHist( smallImg, smallImg );

    t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    cascade.detectMultiScale( smallImg, faces,
        1.1, 2, 0
       // |CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
      //  |CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
        |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
        ,
        Size(30, 30) );
    t = (double)cvGetTickCount() - t;
    printf( "detection time = %g ms\n", t/((double)cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.) );

Comment: for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator r = faces.begin(); r != faces.end(); r++, i++ )
    {
  
        Mat smallImgROI;
        vector<Rect> nestedObjects;
        Point center;
        Scalar color = colors[i%8];
        int radius;
        center.x = cvRound((r->x + r->width*0.5)*scale);
        center.y = cvRound((r->y + r->height*0.5)*scale);
        radius = cvRound((r->width + r->height)*0.25*scale);
        circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        if( nestedCascade.empty() )
            continue;
        smallImgROI = smallImg(*r);

Comment: nestedCascade.detectMultiScale( smallImgROI, nestedObjects,
            1.1, 2, 0
            //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
            |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
            ,
            Size(30, 30) );
           I=I+1;

Comment: for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator nr = nestedObjects.begin(); nr != nestedObjects.end(); nr++ )
        {
            center.x = cvRound((r->x + nr->x + nr->width*0.5)*scale);
            center.y = cvRound((r->y + nr->y + nr->height*0.5)*scale);
            radius = cvRound((nr->width + nr->height)*0.25*scale);
            circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
   printf("X%d=%d  Y%d=%d\n",I, center.x,I,center.y);
   fprintf(f,"%d %d ",center.x,center.y);
   
        }

Comment: this is part of my code that includes the eye detection. last one is mainly for eyes

Answer (score 1):

Use fprintf and a loop. Something like

```
file = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
for (i = 0; i < num_coords; ++i)
{
  fprintf(file, "%d %d %d %d\n", coords[i].left_x, coords[i].left_y, coords[i].right_x, coords[i].right_y);
}
fclose(file);
```

Details will vary depending on exactly how you have the data, of course.

Comment: in my code coords[i] is a point, shall i just change it to array?

Comment: No I wouldn't do that. Why do you think it's wrong to be a point? To get helpful answers you need to **post the code you are having problems with**, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: i have posted above! could you please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> man fopen

and

> man fprintf

Comment: my code is long i can not post it all .... i only have done for one eye coordinate in a line in txt file but i need more than one ... in the next lines in the txt file

Comment: @eyalm: Won't work in, say Visual C++ or C++Builder, i.e. on Windows. Man pages are usually not available in Windows, unless you use one of the GNU setups.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has own interface (both C and C++ versions) for writing files in xml/yaml formats:
[XML/YAML Persistence (C API)](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_xml_yaml_persistence.html)